# How to add BigDecimal values in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have defined two methods that perform a calculation and return a big decimal value.

```
Def Func1
  Model1.price * Model1.qty
End 

Def Func2
   Model2.price * Model2.qty
End
```

I don't know if this relevant, but the :qty field is a counter cache column recording the number of associated has_many records.

I now want to calculate the sum of Func1 and Func2. If I try

```
Def FuncTotal
   Func1 + Func2
End
```

it returns the two values concatenated, not the sum. i.e. if Func1=15.45 and Func2=24.76, then FuncTotal=15.4524.76.

I also tried

```
Def FuncTotal
   Func1.to_s + Func2.to_s
End
```

But this also concatenates.

I assume this issue is occurring because the calculation is based on BigDecimal values. In which case it seems strange to me that the price*qty calculation returns the correct product.

How can I add two BigDecimal values together?

Many thanks

**EDIT**

This is an example console output

```
> 1=Model1.find(1)
=> #<Model1 id:1......
> 2.Model2.find(2)
=> #<Model2 id:2....
> 1total=1.func1
=> [#<BigDecimal:10a5cd888,'0.25E4',9(36)>] 
> 2.total=2func2
=> [#<BigDecimal:10a5c7348,'0.5E3',9(36)>]
> 1+2
=> [#<BigDecimal:10a5cd888,'0.25E4',9(36)>, #<BigDecimal:10a5c7348,'0.5E3',9(36)>]
```

Strange!

**EDIT**

My columns are defined as follows.

Price is the same in both models

```
t.decimal  "price",  :precision => 12, :scale => 2
```

Quantity is more or less the same in both models

```
t.integer  "model1_children_count", :default => 0
```

and in the child model

```
belongs_to :model1, :counter_cache => true
```

**EDIT**

The full Func1 and Func2 is as follows, located within a parent model that has_many Model1s and Model2s.

```
Class Parent
  def total_cost_of_model1
    model1s.collect { |model1s| model1.price * model1.quantity }
  end
end
```

Comment: if you can also show the definition of price and qty it can lead us as to why you're getting Strings

Comment: Thanks for coming over corroded. I've updated the question with column definitions. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: if it would be okay to show at leastt he last few lines of func1 and func2 that would be great. As you can see, you are returning an Array of BigDecimals instead of just one BigDecimal. That is the problem. when you call the method "+" on two Arrays, it will concatenate them and that's why you're getting that result

Comment: Hi corroded, the function is the same as you suggested previously: price*qty but run on an array iterating over all related records. I've updated the question with the code. Is this an example of where the sum function will make my life easier?

Comment: Hi corroded, in Model1 and Model2 I have defined a method `line_total` which calculates `price*qty` for that record. If I perform 'Parent(1).model1s.sum()' on `line_total` and the same on model2, then try to add the results, I get an array. If I run the same on the price column, I get a good result. It seems that the price*qty calculation may be the issue, but I'm unclear why. Appreciate any ideas you may have. Thanks!

Comment: Actually ignore that. running sum on line_total does not work at all, as it is not a valid column

Comment: Oh! I have seen the light! Of course, the collect function was returning an array. This needed to be sum. Things get easier when you come back to them with fresh eyes! Thanks for the great suggestions and walking me through this corroded. Maybe you want to post this as the solution?

Comment: no problem. sorry wasn't able to reply quickly. yes the collect function will return an array so you might need to do a .sum after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your total cost function is calling `collect` which returns an array, which when concatenated will return a concatenated array. You have to return the correct type(BigDecimal) if you want to add it up using "+"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they're BigDecimals? I'm actually getting the correct behavior here.

```
irb(main)> a = BigDecimal.new("1")
=> #<BigDecimal:102773230,'0.1E1',9(18)>
irb(main)> b = BigDecimal.new("2")
=> #<BigDecimal:100dd1a48,'0.2E1',9(18)>
irb(main)> c = a + b
=> #<BigDecimal:1026502e0,'0.3E1',9(27)>
irb(main)> c.to_i
=> 3
```